# Using Template With DOMPDF

Tags: pdf, zend-framework2, dompdf

I am using `DOMPDF` to create a pdf out of my html page. I need to use a specific template for the pdf to be rendered on.

is there a way with `DOMPDF` to use a pdf template for dynamically creating an invoice?

What is the best way to handle this? Would I need to create the template with `html` and `css`?

If it's worth mentioning, I am using `Zend2` and installed `DOMPDF` with `composer`

Comment: dompdf doesn't support PDF templates. You'll ned to create the template in HTML/CSS and populate the HTML document with your variable data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommended to use `zend\pdf` instead of DOMPDF. First it will bit tough but later on you can get high level performance, even able to create 100 pages at one time.

[Invoice generation using Zend Pdf](http://www.sitepoint.com/generating-invoices-with-zend_pdf/)

For your requirement `dompdf` is not a bad choice but

> Noway you can put your template other than using HTML and CSS